# Dat.gui for opacity

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I need to put on a transparency model stl with dat.gui am using the command:

gui.add(opacity_model, 'model').onChange(function(){

```
                if (opacity_model, 'model' ==  true) {
                    material.opacity = 0.0;


                } else {

                    material.opacity = 1.0
                }
```

}

But it does not change the opacity of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting material.transparent = true; or false;